# How to make <td> to break on spaces and only break in word if word is too big for space

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple table element according to the following code:

```css
.simple-table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.simple-table-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.simple-table-big-font {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.simple-table table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: black;
}

.simple-table thead,
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

.simple-table table tbody td {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.simple-table table thead td {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.simple-table-title {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-table ">
    <div class="simple-table-title">Title:</div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Column 1:</td>
          <td>Column 2:</td>
          <td>Column 3:</td>
          <td>Long Column:</td>
          <td>Long Column:</td>
          <td>Very Long Column:</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
          <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This is supposed to work fine, but when I put this component in my application, the table lines are breaking in the middle of my words:

[image]

I need the lines to break on white spaces, and only if the word is too big then break in the word.

I cannot find out what's going on because this table is being rendered inside a chain of dozens of classes and divs.

How can I fix the `simple-table` classes to make sure to have the desired behaviour (break on whitespaces and only break on words if word is too big for horizontal space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you gave performs OK when I try it. I think the property word-break may be set to break-all or break-word somewhere else.
Try forcing it to use "normal".

```
.simple-table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  word-break: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is what was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Bro I have fixed this check on desktop or pc screen

```css
 .simple-table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.simple-table-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.simple-table-big-font {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.simple-table table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: black;
}

.simple-table thead,
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

.simple-table table tbody td {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.simple-table table thead td {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.simple-table-title {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
        td {
            width: 16.66;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="simple-table ">
            <div class="simple-table-title">Title:</div>
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>Column 1:</td>
                <td>Column 2:</td>
                <td>Column 3:</td>
                <td>Long Column:</td>
                <td>Long Column:</td>
                <td>Very Long Column:</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                <td>THIS IS A VERY VERY LONG LONG TEXT</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```